# Why is the limit of a spectral sequence unnatural?

Tags: soft-question, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, spectral-sequences

Fix an Abelian category $\mathscr{A}$, and a homological spectral sequence $(E_{p,q}^r)$, so that $E^{r+1}\cong H(E^r)$, then, according to the [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spectral+sequence), we say that $E^r$ converges to $E^\infty$ if for all $(p,q)$, there exists some $r_0$ such that $r\ge r_0$ implies that $E^{r}_{p,q}\cong E^\infty_{p,q}$. Notably, however, this does not impose any condition on what the isomorphism is, or on naturality of the isomorphism.

I'm really struggling to understand why this is so. My intuition is that any concept in homological algebra that does not impose some sort of condition of naturality, or require an isomorphism to have some unique property, will end up being poorly defined. So why, for spectral sequences, do we allow there to be any isomorphism? If we wanted to define a functor from the category $$\mathbf{ConSpSeq}(\mathscr{A})\to\mathscr{A}$$ of convergent spectral sequences to $\mathscr{A}$ by sending $E$ to $E^\infty_{p,q}$ for fixed $(p,q)$, is it possible to define such a functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better definition is that for $r \ge r_0$ all of the relevant differentials vanish, so that the homology of the page at that index is still $E_{p, q}^r$, which induces a (natural) isomorphism to $E_{p, q}^{r+1}$, etc. So there is a "stable value" of $E_{p, q}^r$ for large $r$, and you can define this to be $E_{p, q}^{\infty}$. This makes $E^{\infty}$ a functor on convergent spectral sequences.

The nLab definition just establishes the isomorphism type of the limit.

Comment: Is it true that the nLab definition is equivalent to this?

Comment: @Monstrous: well, first of all, what you wrote is not what is on the nLab. What is on the nLab is closer to what I wrote, except that it's unclear whether the isomorphism means "some isomorphism" or "the particular map given by the isomorphism between the homology of $E^r$ and $E^{r+1}$." It's common to elide the distinction between these things if the particular map is understood to be clear from context.

Comment: What I mean is, if $E^r$ is isomorphic to its homology on the lower page at every $(p,q)$, then is it true that the differentials vanish? Because the differentials vanishing are given only as an example.

Comment: @Monstrous: what I said was "all of the *relevant* differentials vanish," namely the ones leading into and out of $E_{p, q}^r$. Wikipedia has a more precise statement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sequence#Convergence.2C_degeneration.2C_and_abutment

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of a counterexample along the lines of $$\mathbb{R}^\infty\to\mathbb{R}^\infty\xrightarrow{0}\mathbb{R}^\infty, \ \ (a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\mapsto (a_1,0,a_2,0,a_3,0,\ldots).$$ Now I see that I just took the definition at the nLab too literally.